# R言語で、列の内容に特定の文字列を含む要素を抽出して新しい変数をつくりたい

Tags: r

以下のようなデータに対して、祝日を含む場合は別の変数にして取り扱いたいです。
行は取得したものの、このあとどのように変数をつくればいいかで困っています。

**現状のコード:**

```
ph <- grep("祝日", data)
```

**対象のデータ:**

```
ID 日付 曜日
1　1/1 日曜日
2　2/1 火曜日・祝日
3　3/1 水曜日
・
・
・
```

Answer (score 1):

御質問の主旨は `曜日` 列に `'祝日'` が含まれる「行」を抽出して新しいデータフレームを作る方法と思われます。`grep()`，`grepl()`を使った記述例（`df1`, `df2`）と `tidyverse` パッケージを使った記述例（`df3`）を示します。
なお，実行環境は「macOS 13.3.1(M1), R 4.2.3, tidyverse 2.0.0」です。

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- data.frame(ID=c(1, 2, 3),
                   日付=c('1/1', '2/1', '3/1'),
                   曜日=c('日曜日', '火曜日・祝日', '水曜日'))

df1 <- data[grep('祝日', data$曜日), ]   # grepl() can be also used.
df2 <- subset(data, grepl('祝日', 曜日))

df3 <- data |>
    dplyr::filter(str_detect(曜日, '祝日'))

cat('data:\n')
print(data)
cat('df1:\n')
print(df1)
cat('df2:\n')
print(df2)
cat('df3:\n')
print(df3)
```

```
data:
  ID 日付         曜日
1  1  1/1       日曜日
2  2  2/1 火曜日・祝日
3  3  3/1       水曜日
df1:
  ID 日付         曜日
2  2  2/1 火曜日・祝日
df2:
  ID 日付         曜日
2  2  2/1 火曜日・祝日
df3:
  ID 日付         曜日
1  2  2/1 火曜日・祝日
```

Answer (score 0):

`grep`で列番号が取得できているので

```
ph <- data[grep("祝日", data), ]
```

または、TRUEかFALSEを返す`grepl`を使って

```
ph <- subset(data, grepl("祝日", data))
```